# How to stop mDNSResponder from using 90-100% CPU continuously forever on Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, cpu, dns

I just upgraded my 2018 15" MacBook Pro from Mojave to Catalina (10.15.4). It's been a few hours.

One of the first things I did after the upgrade was edit a video using the new free trial of Final Cut Pro X. My laptop's cooling fans ran full-speed the entire time, but there was always background rendering going on, so I figured that was normal.

When I finished and quit FCP, the fans didn't spin down, so I checked Activity Monitor and discovered that mDNSResponder is taking 90-100% CPU continuously. The Threads column in Activity Monitor indicates 3-4 threads most of the time; the 100% is spread across all of those, and they're not all on the same core. I'm not sure how it's managing to do that and still sit at or just under 100% most of the time, but that's what it's doing.

[image: screenshot of Activity Monitor]

The laptop has six cores (12 logical), so having one core fully occupied does not make a noticeable difference in performance (unless I start measuring how long things take -- but that's noticing that the numbers are different — not that the performance is different!).

Note: In the aggregate, the bar graphs show more than one full core being utilized. This is expected. I have a search applied in my Activity Monitor screenshot, and there's lots of other stuff going on -- Slack is open, Chrome with eleventybillion tabs, IntelliJ IDEA is probably indexing something, and so on.

I tried rebooting mDNSResponder using these commands:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
```

I watched the process disappear, so I know the command worked, but it immediately returned to 100% CPU usage when I started it back up. `mDNSResponderHelper` did not stop, so I tried again, inserting `sudo killall mDNSResponderHelper` as an intermediate step. This made both processes go away as I intended, but still didn't fix the problem.

I also tried sending a HUP signal to mDNSResponder as follows:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

This also had no effect.

I opened up Console, entered `mdnsresponder` in the search field, and watched the messages flow by for a minute or two. Some stuff about Bonjour, LOTS of `<private>`, and some pretty normal-looking DNS query logging. I tried disabling both Bluetooth and Wifi in hopes of affecting Bonjour, but I'm on a hardwired Ethernet connection (which I did not disconnect) and it did not seem to have any effect.

After typing this, I eventually noticed that cloudphotosd was also taking up a healthy chunk of CPU. I assumed that this was the notorious reindexing process that frequently happens after OS upgrades, going through my (quite large) photo library, updating metadata based on whatever new features came with Catalina, and uploading those changes to iCloud. That would explain some constant network activity, and so I thought maybe that would explain mDNSResponder's activity. So I left this window open without submitting and waited a while to see if cloudphotosd would calm down. It did, but mDNSResponder did not. So much for that hunch!

Finally, I tried rebooting my Mac; mDNSResponder wasted no time getting back to business. With no apps running after a fresh boot, it was already consistently sitting at or just under 100%, just like before.

This is a Q&A site, and I haven't asked a question, so here goes: how do I figure out what it is doing, and how do I make it stop?

UPDATE: it's been nearly 48 hours and it's still churning away. My battery life sucks now. I've observed that closing the laptop lid does seem to make it stop, but it comes right back when I open it again. I've also noticed an additional symptom: first-time DNS lookups after a reboot take ~2 seconds (I'd expect <200ms). I'm not sure if that's simply a side effect of mDNSResponder being so busy doing whatever it's doing or if it is related to the cause.

UPDATE 2: it's been more than three weeks. I've added a 100-rep bounty. The DNS lookup delay has increased; it often takes 20-30 seconds, and while there does seem to be some caching in place, I think it has a time-based expiry on it, because the delay reoccurs later without a restart. I'm happy to interact directly with someone knowledgeable enough to debug and diagnose this issue. I'm on Eastern Daylight Time in the United States (UTC-4) and generally available during business hours.

Comment: I don't think it's mDNSResponder per se.  It will periodically scan your network looking for devices, but continually?  No, it shouldn't.  It also responds to DNS requests - if it's doing that while your Mac is sitting idle, something's making requests.  Let's start off by booting in [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262) (Hold `Shift` while booting) to see if the activity stops.

Comment: All that said...I am definitely not a fan of upgrading from one OS to the next; I like clean installs.  In Apple world, things go a bit screwy when upgrading especially which such drastic changes like there is in Catalina.  A clean install may be the solution to this one.

Comment: I’ve been using Macs since ~1990 and have never skipped an OS version. I think I’ve done maybe two clean installs. So FWIW, “in Apple world, things go a bit screwy when upgrading” is maybe a bit of an overstatement.

Comment: I tried Safe Boot a while back — IIRC, mDNSResponder is calm while in that mode, but the behavior comes right back when I go back to regular mode. I will re-verify to be sure.

Comment: I've managed organizations with 1500+ Macs at a time for the better part of a decade and produced reams of technical notes on dealing with these things.  I appreciate your experience, but where I'm coming from is far from "overstating" things.

Comment: I'll wait for the re-verification.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in getting back to this. I’ve never done a bounty before, and did not realize how little time I would have to verify an answer and award someone the bounty! Anyway, I’ve verified that the problem does not exist in Safe Mode. On to the next step....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my recommendation:

1. Let's see what mDNSResponder *is actually doing*. Here's a utility to turn off/on censorship behind the `<private>`label. Make sure to turn it back on once you're done. You may find something like the process is hung up on something and just loops continually, or something like that.
   https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/sierra-console-private/
2. Get a packet capture of your network as you make a DNS request. Grab [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), start a capture on the interface you're using (be it ethernet or WiFi; but make sure the one(s) you're not using are off/unplugged). I would do this first in the environment where it takes 20-30s, and then again after a reboot when the conditions are such that it only takes 2-3s. The less you can have using the network the better as you run these packet captures, as they'll get big fast.
   This should show us the DNS request as well as requests to and from the websites themselves, so we can see where the delays are. If there aren't delays in the network, then we'd look at processes instead.
3. Upload relevant parts of the logs and/or the packet capture(s) somewhere for us to look at. Make sure you censor or remove any private data.
4. And, finally, note that this may be solved faster by doing an in-place OS reinstall. That may oppose your views on *being able* to fix your equipment, knowing what goes on with your equipment, etc., but if the goal is to get mDNSResolver back to sanity as quickly as possible, an in-place OS reinstall *may* be the quickest way there.

EDIT:
I was able to re-create the issue and capture the related network traffic.
Many section of [RFC 6762 (Multicast DNS)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762) seem relevant - I won't post excerpts here, but specifically I found parts of sections 3, 5, 5.2 and 10.2, to be highly relevant.

Here's what I think is happening.

Upon creating these lo0 aliases, traffic is constantly generated with a "cache flush" flag. The RFC doesn't get into enough detail about it for me to be sure, but it seems like each of the loopback addresses are advertising themselves as being *the* address that can respond to queries made to the hostname of the machine, and therefore listening devices should flush their internal caches and update them with the new IP address.

Think about it, if the network thinks you're `hostname.local` at `192.168.44.111` and your IP address changes, mDNS will blast out a "flush your caches, `hostname.local` is now `192.168.44.123`!" message on `224.0.0.251`. This is one circumstance where mDNS will proactively advertise a new IP, and it's the reason network browsing works so well - i.e., networked printers as per the RFC.

What doesn't make a ton of sense to me, is there are parts of the RFC that have me think multiple active loopback addresses on the same machine wouldn't be spamming the way they are - but then I may not be understanding the RFC well. Either way, it seems clear to me that the `mDNSResponder` process is looping through each loopback interface and telling everyone on `224.0.0.251` to disregard the last guy who took charge, *this* is the new IP address assigned to my hostname!

I'm not exactly clear on why this slows down regular DNS queries, except if `mDNSResponder` is responsible for sending out and receiving the regular DNS queries, well, it's tied up in all this nonsense with the other interfaces. And/or, perhaps the DNS queries would go out and come back in on whichever interface has most recently taken charge of the hostname. That, I could see really causing delays, because in the time a DNS request over WAN comes back, the responding loopback interface would be different than the one it went out from. But I'm just spitballing wildly at this point.

Further, instead of having to restart, you can change your script slightly.
If `ifconfig lo0 alias "$ADDR" up` was used to bring up a new interface alias, then
`ifconfig lo0 -alias "$ADDR"` can be used to bring it down.

Comment: If you know how to make DNS requests from the command-line, that might be better than visiting a website with your browser, because it cuts out everything other than the DNS request. Also, this will show us parts of what the network is doing, but not the process: for that we may have to employ `fs_usage`, if it looks like the network _isn't_ doing anything unexpected.

Comment: I don't know if you know this, but "george" is active here.  Also, can you expand on what the OP should be looking for *after* turning off the private label?  There's lots of info in the log. As for the Wireshark log...what constitutes "relevant?"

Comment: I had no idea George was here, that's awesome. What's his username?
Regarding logs and Wireshark, there are many things that might be relevant, and I can't list or even predict them all. One example might be if OP is using Google's public DNS yet requests are actually taking 20s on an otherwise-fine connection. If we see that show up in the packet trace, we might also see where the delay is (going out or coming back). If it doesn't show up in the packet trace (eg packets went out and came back quickly), we can assume it's an issue in a process, not the network.

Comment: So, it must be something other than _just_ DNS requests. If I use `dig` or `nslookup` at the command line, queries come back instantly (~0.05s). I have some additional info. The problem persists regardless of the following: wired or wifi. ISP-provided DNS or Google DNS. Disabled my work-provided GlobalProtectDNS. Disabled Dropbox and Google Drive's syncing daemons. Other devices on my home network are not affected.

Comment: I tried George's tool. It runs, reports that the current status is "disabled", but if I try to use it to enable, it fails with exit code = 8. A subsequent status check confirms that it is still disabled, and I still see lots of `<private>` in the Console.

Comment: One mDNSResponder message in the Console that I can see, and which I didn't notice before, is `WARNING: UDP packet reception took 1046 ms to complete`. Seems relevant.

Comment: Another finding: after disabling both wifi and bluetooth and disconnecting my ethernet cable, I still see high CPU utilization by the mDNSResponder process.

Comment: WireShark very quickly showed that there is a LOT of traffic on the local loopback interface. The wired Ethernet interface is mostly quiet, showing activity only when something is happening that would warrant it (e.g. loading a page). I've performed a packet capture and skimmed through some things, but I don't really know what I'm looking for.

Comment: One thing I can see in my packet capture: ten packets in quick succession (within 0.001s of each other), then two seconds of silence -- repeat forever. The gaps are generally a bit longer than two seconds. After 30 seconds, it had "fallen behind" by a cumulative 0.51 seconds.

Comment: All of the packets have protocol "MDNS". They come in pairs -- one IPv4, one IPv6. Each is going from localhost (127.0.0.1 or fe80::1) to the standard MDNS multicast address (224.0.0.251 or ff02::fb).

Comment: Lengths vary, but the IPv6 packet is always 20 bytes longer than its IPv4 mate. This is accounted for by the difference in header lengths in the protocols themselves. The MDNS portions of the paired packets appear to be identical.

Comment: _All_ of the captured packets are responses. None are requests. It's unclear to me what they're responding to or how to figure that out.

Of note: as part of my work, I do a lot of testing with local server clusters. As such, I have many (small hundreds) of loopback IPs configured, ranging from the standard 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.10.30 (not including every address in that range). Each MDNS response packets contain "answer" records for my Mac's machine name (the one ending in .local) and a subset (~80) of those IP addresses.

Comment: I disabled my launchctl script which creates those loopback interfaces on startup, and rebooted my machine. mDNSResponder's CPU utilization is currently 0.0%. Wireshark shows relative silence on lo0. My laptop's fans are inaudible. And, perhaps most importantly, Chrome and Safari once again load pages as quickly as my other devices. I'm no longer frequently using all of those loopbacks, and so I will most likely just bring them up as needed from now on rather than on startup. I will probably also only bring up as many as I need, rather than enough that I never have to worry about it!

Comment: I've upvoted and accepted this answer. Apologies that I'm no longer able to award the bounty. One final note: this behavior was definitely new with Catalina. I operated Mojave for months with all of those loopback IPs and never had a problem. I wonder what changed!

Comment: @JakeRobb nice work! Wondering if you’d be willing to share the script with me so I can reproduce it on my end. I’m very curious about what mDNS is doing.

Comment: Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/jakerobb/8c2f2d4912b788d7b8e36dc503fa17be

Comment: Came back to look at this in regard to a meta conversation about bounties (I really wish I could have awarded @Harv the rep he deserves!). Now I'm just wondering if he ever had time to try reproducing this or if he got anywhere from there. :)

Comment: Ah, honestly I let it get buried in a pile of other things. I'll make time to try it out tonight. :)

Comment: @JakeRobb edits made. Apologies if it's sloppy, I'm rather tired. I hope it helps, and sorry I just don't know mDNS well enough to comment more than this.

Comment: For what it's worth, the command to get rid of the <private> in the log files is `sudo log config --mode "private_data:on"`

Answer (score -2):

This can be a lot of things, but all involving remote/sharing via the internet.

Do you have Screen Sharing, Remote Login, Remote Management, Bluetooth Sharing, or even Bonjour activated?

One of these things could be generating all of these DNS traffic.

On the other hand, this can be a Malware. Try to clean all your DNS cache and change it to `0.0.0.0`

To flush DNS cache:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```